# Termination condition in an NDA

Tags: contract-law, india

Party A ( from India, is the service provider) signed a NDA with a Party B ( from KSA, service buyer). The parties did not mention any termination condition in the agreement.

Now after 4 years, the Party A (from India)   would like to terminate this NDA. What is the  legally correct  way to do this ?

Comment: In my experience, NDA's don't terminate. The purpose of the NDA is to assure whichever party is providing proprietary information that the other party won't share this information without permission - *ever*. An NDA doesn't force you to continue to do business with someone, it just ensures that you don't leak their secrets.

Answer (score 2):

Party A or Party B could die (or be wound up if they are companies).